# How to specify layout in res.render function?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I need to have different layouts when render a view (Expressjs 2.x). How to change them ? 
For example:

```
res.render('follow_page', {layout:'layout_2'}, {name:'test'})

res.render('user_page', {layout:'layout_1'}, {user:'test1'})
```

Comment: What version of Express are you using? As layouts are no longer supported in 3.x, opting instead for techniques within the template engine of choice -- such as Jade's [Template Inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11).

Comment: thanks, I have updated question. Expressjs 2.x

Answer (score 0):

For Express 2.x and earlier, you'll want to merge the 2 objects, giving it a `locals` property:

```
res.render('follow_page', { layout: 'layout_2', locals: { name: 'test' } });
res.render('user_page', { layout: 'layout_1', locals: { name: 'test1' } });
```